# Remove from database a binding linq2sql object

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, bindingsource

I have a simple list from linq2sql query and a bindingsource as datasource of a grid.

```
Dim query As IQueryable(Of HORARIOS_MEDICOS) = From o In context.HORARIOS_MEDICOS Where o.medico_id = 1 Select o
BindingSource1.DataSource = query.ToList
```

I have a button in grid that trigger a remove of the selected row in bindingsource (I use janus grid)

```
 Private Sub GridEX1_ColumnButtonClick(sender As Object, e As Janus.Windows.GridEX.ColumnActionEventArgs) Handles GridEX1.ColumnButtonClick
    Dim hora As HORARIOS_MEDICOS = GridEX1.CurrentRow.DataRow
    BindingSource1.Remove(hora)
    BindingSource1.EndEdit()

End Sub
```

After I make a context.submitchanges(). Is supposed that bindingsource.remove mark this object to delete and submitchanges must delete this from the database but doesn't work. Of course context that load the list and context that submit changes is the same.

I'm thinking to make something like this:

```
   BindingSource1.Remove(hora)
   context.HORARIOS_MEDICOS.DeleteOnSubmit(hora)
```

But I think it make no sense with binding controls.

Comment: Bind the `query`, not `query.ToList`.

Comment: Pefect.. thanks.. i thought binding must be with enumerable/list directly and not with queryable  .. thanks you very much